# Set view variables in controller for partials in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there any way to set variables for the partial in the controller level?

Because everytime I need variables inside a partial I always have to pass them:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->partial('travels/_steps.phtml', 
                        array('searchHotel' => $this->searchHotel, 
                              'actionName'  => $this->actionName)) 
?>
```

I would really just like `actionName` to be available on all partials - for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the Zend_View_Helper_Partial class to a class that keeps that variable in scope.  You would need to override the cloneView() function:

```
public function cloneView()
{
    $view = parent::cloneView();
    $view->actionName = $this->view->actionName
    return $view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$this->render()` instead. With it, you wouldn't need to pass the view variables every time.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

You could also just sent the current view as a parameter to the partial:

```
<?php 
  echo $this->partial('travels/_steps.phtml', array('parentView' => $this));
```

Then, in the partial:

```
<?php
  $view = $this->parentView;
  echo $view->searchHotel, $view->actionName;
```

Answer (score -2):

In my humble opinion, you're doing exactly what you're supposed to do - passing just those variables you'll need in the partial.

If this causes you pain, perhaps you might consider that you're using partials unnecessarily.

Or, put another way, if you want to have some variable available in all partials then perhaps the partial is not where you should be using those variables.

Maybe have a look at [Placeholders](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder) and rethink how you go about rendering your views.

Comment: sorry but i just want a convenient way to access some common variables in my partials, no need to complicate things.

Comment: The idea behind partials is their limited variable scope, thus you pass to it just the variables you need. It isn't an inconvenience, unless you're misusing them.

Comment: I would rather say the partials should be used to avoid duplicating code, rather than limiting their variable scope (but it is probably a consequence)